# Не вносятся данные в таблицу

Tags: php, mysqli

Что не так? Все названия правильные, кавычки тоже вроде, но данные не вносятся. Значения переменных тоже передается( делал echo($Query), чтоб проверить.
Ошибок не выдает, в чем дело?

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$Link=mysqli_connect('localhost','id1396307_eletctrrr','2002vm','id1396307_chattab');
$Query="INSERT INTO `id1396307_chattab`.`usertab` (`id`, `username`, `name`, `sname`, `email`, `password`, `age`, `sex`, `country`, `city`)
VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[lgn]', '$_POST[nm]', '$_POST[snm]', '$_POST[eml]', 
'$_POST[pwd]', '$_POST[age]', $_POST[sex], '$_POST[cntr]', '$_POST[ct]')";
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_query($Link, $Query);
mysqli_close($Link);
?>
```

Comment: У вас покажется только ошибка соединения, а для ошибки именно MySQL нужно использовать mysqli_error. Или просто сделайте echo запроса и попробуйте его выполнить через phpmyadmin.

Comment: Спасибо, MySQL подсказал что я у одной переменной кавычки забыл, теперь работает

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы получить последнюю ошибку Mysqli, нужно воспользоваться функцией  [mysqli.error](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php) и в зависимости от ошибки нужно предпринимать действия.

```
$erroroMessage = mysqli_error($link);
```

Если это не поможет понять проблему, то можно посмотреть файл логов mysql, которые обычно находятся в /var/log/mysql/*

Comment: `$errorMessage = mysqli_error($Link); echo($errorMessage);`
Ошибку не выдал